# Double tap does not work after a quick action

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

In my application, I have one "NEXT" button and a lots of images.When i click on NEXT button, next image in the sequence is shown in the screen. and When i double tap on image the image will get zoomed.

Now My Problem is when a click on NEXT button very frequently, at least ten times, after that double tap on image, image would not zoomed. Even Double tap event does not occour . But when I double tap again,it gets zoomed.

I want on first double tap, image should be zoomed.

Comment: How are you doing the changing between images? How are you doing the double tap? How are you doing the zooming? - Any or all of these could affect your code.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried creating a double click event? Something similar to this question: [How to make Image doubleclick event in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5460352/how-to-make-image-doubleclick-event-in-c)

Answer (score 0):

At a guess I suspect that when you're changing the displayed image many times in quick succession the image changes are getting queued up and so when you doubletap the image currently displayed and the image being zoomed aren't the same.